# Product Integral version of $\sum_{p\leq x}p^{-s}.$

Tags: number-theory, improper-integrals

This sum $$\sum_{p\leq x}p^{-s}.$$ can be written using  Riemann Stieltjes integral and using partial integration under conditions: infinite series converges absolutely if Re(s) > 1, so assuming that Re(s) < 1.

$$\sum_{p\leq x}p^{-s}=\int_{2}^{x}t^{-s}d\left(\pi(t)\right)=t^{-s}\pi(t)\biggr|_{2}^{x}+s\int_{2}^{x}t^{-s-1}\pi(t)dt.$$

My question is is there a Product Integral that can be used to make an equivalent product version of the above sum? Is this even possible?$$\prod_{p\leq x}p^{-s}.$$

$$\prod_{p\leq x}p^{-s}=\prod_{2}^{x}t^{-s}\,d\left(\pi(t)\right)^{dt}$$

Comment: one could use $\log p_n\# = \sum_{k=1}^n \log p_n,$ and $\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n \log p_n &=& \int_2^n \log k\;  d\pi(k)\\
&=& \log(k)\pi(k)\biggr|_{2}^{n}+\int_{2}^{n}\frac1k \pi(k)dk.
\end{eqnarray}$ as a work around but that is not what I'm after. Rather a Product Integral solution to the problem.

Comment: What do you mean ? For $\Re(s) \in (1/2,1)$, using the prime number theorem : $$\prod_{p \le x} (1 - p^{-s})= \exp(\sum_{p\le x} \log(1-p^{-s})) = \exp(-\sum_{p\le x} p^{-s}+\mathcal{O}(p^{-2s}))\\=\exp(C-\sum_{p\le x} p^{-s})=  \exp(C-\sum_{n\le x} \frac{n^{-s}}{\log n} + o(\sum_{n \le x}\frac{|n^{-s}|}{\log^k n})) =  \exp(C-\frac{N^{1-s}}{\log n}+o(\frac{N^{1-s}}{\log^k n}))$$ Under the RH the error term is improved to $\mathcal{O}(N^{1/2+\epsilon-s})$

Comment: And $\prod_{p \le x} p^{-s} = \exp(-s \sum_{p \le x} \log p) =\exp(-s (x+o(\frac{x}{\log^k x}))$

Comment: @reuns thanks, yes I did not consider $\prod_{p \le x} (1 - p^{-s})$ before posting.  I will think about this a bit more.